# Private PKI vs IoT certificates vs WebAuthn

Tags: security, pki, webauthn, mtls, aws-iot-core

I'm building an identity service where we're supposed to use PKI and MTLS to authenticate users for security reasons.

We're currently using AWS Private ACM for hosting a private root CA as well as an Intermediate CA that issues end-entity certificates for our users which works.
However, we're a startup and the cost of having 2 private CA's at AWS is $800 / month which is a bit steep.
We've been recommended to use IoT Core for issuing certificates instead of a Private CA with the argument that IoT Core can handle a lot more certificates than a Private CA.
However, since I'm neither a PKI expert nor an IoT expert, I'm not exactly sure what the security implications would be.

Another possibility would be to use WebAuthn, but it's the same here, I'm not really sure if I'm able to evaluate if WebAuthn is secure enough or not.
Is WebAuthn considered as secure as PKI?

One of the reasons we want to use PKI is that it's an old standard that even is accepted as authentication method by banks.
Would the security be on the same level using IoT Core generated certificates or WebAuthn?

Comment: Assuming "users" mean employees of your company? Can you elaborate on these "security reasons" - are there standards you need to follow?

Perhaps this FIDO Alliance white paper can help, it compares PKI smartcards to WebAuthn for use by the US government: https://media.fidoalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/White-Paper-Leveraging-FIDO-Standards-to-Extend-the-PKI-Security-Model-in-US-Govt-Agencies.pdf

Comment: No, the users are anyone.
The security reasons is that we need the security to meet the bank standard.
Thanks, I'll read through it :)